# Suppose that $\sum a_i$ converges and that $a_i\geq0$ for all .

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Suppose that $\sum a_n$ converges and that $a_n\geq0$ for all $n$. For each $n$, let $e_n=\pm1$. Then, prove that $\sum e_na_n$ converges.

Can I simply say that ∑|eᵢaᵢ| = ∑aᵢ so that ∑eᵢaᵢ converges absolutely, and hence converges?

Comment: Where do you get stuck? Use the definition and show that the partial sums are a Cauchy sequence.

Comment: Can I simply say that  ∑|eᵢaᵢ| =  ∑aᵢ so that ∑eᵢaᵢ converges absolutely, and hence converges?

Comment: If you're allowed to use this theorem, yes. What you asked is pretty much the proof of the theorem.

Answer (score 1):

For all $M > N \geq 1$, $$0 \leq \left\lvert \sum_{n=N}^M e_n a_n \right\rvert \leq \sum_{n=N}^M \vert a_n \rvert \leq \sum_{n=N}^\infty a_n \xrightarrow[N\to\infty]{} 0.$$

(actually, one should technically see that as a 2-step thing: first let $M$ go to $\infty$ to get that $\left\lvert \sum_{n=N}^\infty e_n a_n \right\rvert$ is well-defined, and then let $N$ go to $\infty$ to show that the remainder of the series goes to $0$, hence the series converges).